# Excel 2016 Relationship

Tags: excel, relationship

**Goal**

Create a working relationship between my Category Sales and Voids PivotTables so I can leverage one slicer for all data.

**Background**

Using two PowerQueries, I pull in data from SQL to Excel.  Because Sales and Voids have DateStamp and StoreID columns in common, I essentially concatenate these in the SQL query to create an ID.  For example:

```
select concat(StoreID,convert(int,DateStamp)) as ID, DateStamp, StoreID, Category, Sales from...
select concat(StoreID,convert(int,DateStamp)) as ID, DateStamp, StoreID, Voids from...
```

This is a one-to-many relationship between the two (Sales --> Voids)

**Problem**

Despite creating the relationship in Excel (through Manage Relationships, as PowerPivot is not available) I can't get it to apply and Excel tells me relationships between tables may be needed.  I've no idea what I'm doing wrong.

**Workaround**

The only workaround I can think of is to take the void value for a given day and divide by the number of categories that have sales, then just do a join to create one table that I pull into Excel.  It would technically work for my application, but I'd love to know why the relationship isn't working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to export your data into the data model so that you can use power pivot, PLUS a export another power query (or several) into the data model that is a deduplicated table of keys.

Then, in the data model editor, set up the data relationships so that there is a one to many relationship between your deduplicated key table(s) and the "actual data".

Then, in a power pivot, use those "key" tables as much as possible, maybe even to the ruthless ideal(1) of using ONLY key tables in your primary row and column headers, and if you have a second level of categorization then a deduplicated table of primary to secondary, and so on, then using the real data tables only in the body of your power pivot.

*(1) - Keep in mind that this is just an ideal I'm just explaining to help you understand and maybe start moving towards as much as actually makes sense. As with most things, in reality, the ideal is almost never worth reaching because there are other factors (like your own patience and time).*

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have PowerPivot. (See Problem section.)  Perhaps just a shortcoming of Excel's 'standard' relationship building is that it can't handle one-to-many?

Comment: Can you load values to the data model and do a pivot table off that? If so, then (1) that's what you need and (2) my definition of "power pivot" is probably wrong because I thought a power pivot was just a pivot using the data model!

Comment: My PowerQueries both are loaded into the Data Model, which I then build PivotTables from.  But, unfortunately, this is where the problem sits. PowerPivot is a COM add-in which might facilitate a viable solution, but is not included in all versions of Excel, unfortunately.